# How to extract vertices given in an .stl file (exported from 3ds max) into multiple arrays of floats using c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have an .stl file with the following format (here representing a random 2D rectangle centered on the origin),

```
solid Object01
    facet normal 0.000000e+00 -0.000000e+00 1.000000e+00
        outer loop
            vertex -1.797776e+01 2.198619e+01 0.000000e+00
            vertex -1.797776e+01 -2.198619e+01 0.000000e+00
            vertex 1.797776e+01 2.198619e+01 0.000000e+00
        endloop
    endfacet
    facet normal -0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 1.000000e+00
        outer loop
            vertex 1.797776e+01 -2.198619e+01 0.000000e+00
            vertex 1.797776e+01 2.198619e+01 0.000000e+00
            vertex -1.797776e+01 -2.198619e+01 0.000000e+00
        endloop
    endfacet
endsolid Object01
```

and what I am looking to do is extract the numbers following each "vertex" into an array of floats such that I have a unique array of floats representing the triangle that is each facet. i.e. here this would produce 2 3x3 arrays (in this instance the 0's are redundant but this won't always be the case for me with this problem).

Anyone got any pointers on how to proceed?

Comment: You have three options: 1) use scanf, 2) use reg-ex 3) write your own parser. Better, look at how to do 3 because is more flexible. For 3) most simple is to start reading the file line by line and then word by word (search for such std iterators).

Comment: Ok, I'll have a look at that approach, thanks for the pointers.